# onclick toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i click on the class `dropdown-toggle` the class which is empty `<li class="">` should be changed as open .. like `<li class="open">`

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z072LqLy/1/)

Here is my Script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
    $("ul li.current").toggleClass("open");
    alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

I tried as when ever i click the class `dropdown-toggle` toggle the class by `toggleClass`.

But it is not toggling. What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the clicked `li` element which is the parent of the clicked `dropdown-toggle`, so you can use `this` and `.closest()` to find it like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
.open .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="menu-text"> First </span></a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class=""><a href="tables.html">Add First</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="jqgrid.html">Edit First</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="menu-text"> Second </span></a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class=""><a href="tables.html">Add Second</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="jqgrid.html">Edit Second</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have simple solution like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

toggle class has already in jquery ,so use toggle() event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("body").on("click",".dropdown-toggle",function(){
       $(this).find("li").toggle();
       alert("clicked");
     });
});

<li class="">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="menu-text"> First </span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Add First</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Edit First</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="menu-text"> Second </span>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Add Second</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Edit Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
</li>
```

`